# Python list() vs append()

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a list of lists from a `csv` file.

> Row 1 of `CSV` is a line describing the data source
>
> Row 2 of `CSV` is the header
>
> Row 3 of `CSV` is where the data starts

There are two ways I can go about it but I don't know why they're different.

First is the using `list()` and for some reason the result of this ignores row 1 and row 2 of the `CSV`.

```py
data = []
with open(datafile,'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = ','))

return (name, data)
```

Whereas if I use `.append()`, I'd have to use `.next()` to skip row 2

```py
data = []
with open(datafile,'rb') as f:
    file = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    next(file)

    for line in file:
        data.append(line)

return (name, data)
```

Why does `list()` ignores the row with all the header whereas `append()` doesn't?

Comment: Your first example doesn't make sense, you're trying to read the file as CSV while also iterating over it. You probably want to skip the first line of the file *before* passing it to the CSV reader.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't understand it either. It actually only iterates it once and it skips over the header row and makes a list of lists of exactly what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not related to python's `list()` or `append()`,  it is related to the logic you have used in the first snippet.

**The program is not skipping the header, it is replacing it**.
For every line in the loop, you are assigning a new value to `data`. So it is a new list , as it overwrites everything that was there previously.

Correct code :

```
data = []
with open(datafile,'rb') as f:
 next(f)
 for line in f:
    data.extend(line.split(","))

return (name, data)
```

This will just extend the existing list with a new list that is passed as an argument, and there is no problem with 2nd snippet.

Comment: This code returns a list, but I need a list of lists. The first snippet iterates once and returns the whole csv in a list of lists.